# How to overload function template function inside a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

How can I overload the `Contains` function template in class template `Range`?

When I run this code , I get an error as below:

```
template <typename T>
class Range {
public:
    Range(T lo, T hi) : low(lo), high(hi)
    {}

    typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, bool>::type    
    Contains(T value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
    {
        // do sth
        return true;
    }

    typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, bool>::type 
    Contains(T value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
    {
        // do sth
        return true;
    }
};
```

```
error: ‘typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<_Tp>::is_integer, bool>::type Range<T>::Contains(T, bool, bool) const’ cannot be overloaded
         Contains(T value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
         ^~~~~~~~
    error: with ‘typename std::enable_if<(! std::numeric_limits<_Tp>::is_integer), bool>::type Range<T>::Contains(T, bool, bool) const’
         Contains(T value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
```

Comment: On a side note: consider using [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) instead of `std::numeric_limits::is_integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `Contains` themselves template too. E.g.

```
template <typename X>
typename std::enable_if<!std::numeric_limits<X>::is_integer, bool>::type    
Contains(X value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
{
    // do sth
    return true;
}

template <typename X>
typename std::enable_if<std::numeric_limits<X>::is_integer, bool>::type 
Contains(X value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
{
    // do sth
    return true;
}
```

Since C++17 you can use *Constexpr If* instead of overloading.

```
bool
Contains(T value, bool leftBoundary = true, bool rightBoundary = true) const
{
    if constexpr (!std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer) {
        // do sth
        return true;
    } else {
        // do sth
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please to explain why you need `template <typename X = T>` instead of `template <typename X >`

Comment: @long.kl It's unnecessary since the template argument could be deduced. I'll remove it.